# How do I react and handle this situation with a condescending employee?

Tags: management, united-states

I have a receptionist that gets condescending every time management addresses any issues with her.

The other day she rearranged her office and our IT person had requested I talk with her, as only IT should move the equipment around. She had rearranged her office and placed the ink jet printer in front of a window with a 98 °F (37 °C) plus temperature on the outside of the window.

I called the receptionist in and ask her to move the printer away from the window due to the heat.

A couple of hours (?) after asking her I was told by another employee that she stated she was not going to take my reprimands, that she was going to quit and wanted the other employees to quit all at the same time, by just walking out together. This employee came to me and stated the receptionist did a good job, but that he had no intentions of leaving and didn't want her to leave either, but wanted what she was saying and doing about wanting all employees to leave to stop.

Is there a way I can rehabilitate this receptionist, or should she be let go?

Comment: I edited this.  I didn't know the time frame for the fourth paragraph.  Please let me know if it's not hours.

Comment: Frankly, I would be inclined to ask her just one question: "I've been told by other employees that you intend to leave the company. Do you want to formally hand in your notice, or would you prefer to just leave your security pass on the desk and go right now?"

Comment: Did she move the printer?

Comment: @alphazero - no. You don't give the employee the opportunity to screw things up on her way out the door. If you consider the report of her statements to be accurate you call HR, have her final check made out through the end of the day, call her into your office, and let her go, assuming she's on an "at will" contract - i.e. she can terminate her employment whenever she wants, and you can terminate her employment whenever *you* want. If she's this poisonous you don't need her around, and any minor inconvenience caused by her absence will be survivable.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri : I presume so.  OP did say, "She" ... "placed the ink jet printer".  Granted, we don't necessarily have the full story.  We only have the details that OP provided.  Unless we see clear reason to doubt those details, we are typically best off assuming that they are accurate.  Otherwise, this whole site ends up second-guessing things so much that questioning the validity of every fact takes up much more time (and reading the most useful information ends up being something that is a much smaller percentage of our time).

Comment: Can you explain the "condescending" part?

Comment: So does this employee have a long history of serious workplace drama? There's a lot of disagreement in the answers/comments below about whether the report from this fellow employee can be trusted. Is this person a known troublemaker?

Comment: It would be really nice to get OP's edit with clarification. I don't like this question, because it barely holds sense and mentions only one situation, stating there was more, and not even being specific on this one. I don't believe a receptionist would try to start up basically a full-fledged protest in the office, because someone forbids her to rearrange the office freely, due to technical reasons (sic!). This seems out of proportions by magnitudes. Btw is it normal that a receptionist have an office? I always thought the job is to receive people at some kind of lobby.

Comment: Obviously her response needs to be addressed, but when you know she has a history of this type of response, why would you call her to your office just to tell her to move a printer? Walk over to her desk and tell her. She'll be less defensive and more open to the suggestion. Guessing from her reaction it wouldn't have changed anything, but it might with other employees in the future.

Comment: @mattdm - I was wondering the same. This sounds like plain insubordination, nothing condescending about it. I can be condescending myself from time to time, when given really dumb suggestion while under pressure, but the behaviour described in the question is simply rude and worthy of disciplinary action.

Comment: @TOOGAM: No, I mean did she move the printer away from the window after OP instructed her to? IOW did she merely *talk* mutiny, or did she *act* mutiny? As congusbongus points out below, OP has only other employee's word about office conversation and needs to verify that receptionist is fomenting mutiny. But if the printer is still sitting in the hot sun then no further investigation is indicated.

Comment: I agree with @JoeStrazzere we need to know if you are her boss here. If you aren't, stay out, none of your business. If you are, you get to make the decision to address the issue with her directly, reprimand her, fire her, or forgive her and let her stay. Based on you hearing the gossip from some other employee it sounds like there is a lack of direct communication. Take the time to sit down with her and talk to her if she is your employee.

Comment: I don't want to be mean to anyone, but you should ask yourself: do you want someone working for you that's considering quitting over the placement of a printer?

Answer (score 100):

That is open insubordination.  Fire her yesterday!  No apologies, no warning.

Call a temp service, get help, and walk her out the door immediately.

The difficult here is a far cry short of the pain you're going to have if you give this person one more week in the office.  People like this are the equivalent of a cancer.  They metastasize and spread the bad attitude to good people near them.  You've already seen it start with the employee who came to you with this information.

This is something you cannot wait on.  There is no warning.  There is no performance improvement plan.  This is open mutiny, and the only way to deal with mutiny is the navy way.  Fire her.  Take the hit with unemployment premiums and temp rates until you can rehire.  The few dollars that will cost is NOTHING compared to recruiting and training to replace the half dozen others she'll sour if this continues.

Wothwhile Reading:  [How to get rid of toxic employees](http://www.bizjournals.com/bizjournals/how-to/human-resources/2012/01/how-to-get-rid-of-toxic-employees.html).

Comment: Worth noting is that OP didn't hear the receptionist say those things directly, but via hearsay.

Comment: Depends where you are. In my country, which has freedom (for employees!), you can't fire somebody for this... especially _someone_ like this. You'll be in employment tribunal by the end of the week.

Comment: Unless thats an at will contract firing may be illegal. In my country for instance you'd have to issue a "Abmahnung", a written reprimand, before firing, and you can't fire for the same action you reprimanded people for.

Comment: Regardless of what country you are in, if you *do* pursue this path, you should consult your HR department for the appropriate path to take in seeing this employee out the door.  But, with that much insubordination (and since she *did* move company equipment without permission already), you have plenty of reasonable grounds to reprimand her, if not terminate her employment.

Comment: @congusbongus - The OP said that this is a recurring pattern with this employee, and these two incidents (unauthorized equipment relocation, harassing of other employees) are just the latest examples.  Outside of that context, I'd agree with you.

Comment: You only got one downvote, so there must not be too much thinking :p.  But I disagree with the strong-arm tactic. (no, I'm not the downvote) Build a file first to protect yourself from lawsuits.  Run her through a PIP so you can document everything

Comment: Also, note that this position is the *receptionist*, typically your first contact with customers. Arguably the most important position in the company.

Comment: @RichardU - There are very few occasions when you have to go this route, but when someone is actively trying to subvert management and cause material damage to the company (convincing others to quit), it **IS** one of those occasions.

Comment: @WesleyLong If the manager had first-hand knowledge of this, yes, if it's just office gossip, no.

Comment: @RichardU - An employee making a report on events in the office that are impacting the business to management is not "gossip."  Especially if it's more than one employee.  My company had two employees doing this about 18 months ago.  We tried to rehabilitate them.  Didn't work. Had to fire them.  It took us almost a year to get operations back to normal because of all the animosity they caused.

Comment: @WesleyLong you still have to confirm before you take action or you are begging for a lawsuit.

Comment: I can't believe so many people are upvoting (and so few downvoting) an answer that recommends sacking someone outright, based on nothing but hearsay (and possibly a personality clash with the asker). If she really is such a "problem employee", there will be much more evidence of it than this one report from one person who could have a grudge or agenda.

Comment: According to the OP's telling, this person is on the verge of quitting, so the better approach would probably be to goad her into it.  She'd rather quit than move the printer?  Great!  Make her move the printer, might solve your problem right there.  Giving the problem employee more rope can only work to the employer's advantage, either in providing opportunities to document reasons for termination-with-cause, or causing the employee to quit or do something that's grounds for immediate termination.  (Or who knows, maybe you even discover the employee's not toxic... anything's possible.)

Comment: I don't see where you got "insubordination".  As far as I can tell, the employee is *alleged* only to have been upset and talked about quitting.  (And I don't understand why the word "condescending" was used.) Even if we assume that she said what she is reported to have said, was it a sincere threat, or just blowing off steam? No way to know.  But I didn't see any claim that the employee actually disobeyed orders.

Comment: Incidentally, the [Navy way](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/10/894) of handling mutiny involves a little more than firing...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : until you’re getting some evidences…

Answer (score 55):

OK. How to deal with toxic employees has been covered in other answers - but I suspect you may have a different issue on your hands.

A few points:

1. You may want to consider the possibility that the other employees are trying to get the receptionist fired. I don't know the social atmosphere in your workplace, but in many cases, management / ownership are kept out of the loop when it comes to personal drama between employees that has leaked onto the job. In addition, employees (as both individuals and groups) can have their own agendas, which you *certainly* won't be hearing about.
2. [Workplace Mobbing](http://www.workplacebullying.org/individuals/problem/definition/) is real. I've been a witness to it. I've been a victim of it. It happens in a number of circumstances, the least of which could be relationship / sex drama or simple personality conflicts.
3. As a general rule, employees are well aware that they can take advantage of disciplinary procedure and chain of command to jeopardize an 'undesirable' or strategically inconvenient co-worker's position.
4. In some situations, this is done as part of a 'Neighborhood Watch'
   or 'Community Policing' program if an individual is acting in a way
   that members of the group deem to be strange, or is clearly engaged in  illegal activities for which no legal warrant can be obtained for a legitimate
   investigation. The primary objective in these cases is to drive them out of their jobs and out of their homes if possible. A secondary objective may be to provoke them to do something that lands them in jail for at least an equal amount of time as the crimes they are suspected of committing.
5. If this is a case of mobbing (no matter the reason), being out of the loop should put the fear of God in you - even as a manager. Once the perpetrators successfully get rid of the receptionist, there is a possibility that they could target you at some point in the future. Or even next. Management is not invincible. *I have seen this happen*.
6. If you simply terminate the receptionist without analyzing the situation, you may be helping to propagate a serious form of abuse. This isn't a group of school children taking each others' toys and calling names.

   *Lives have been lost on numerous occasions due to this type of harassment.*

   **Note this well.**

But for what it's worth, using only the information you provided, my analysis of the situation would indicate that something fishy may indeed be going on behind the scenes.

Here's why:

- *Both* the IT person and the other employee immediately ran to you over a problem that could have been handled by any reasonably mature adult employee without the need for managerial intervention. While it is true that reprimands and orders can only be given by management, this particular problem could have been solved without the need for either.
- *A simple non-confrontational conversation between the IT person and the receptionist could have eliminated the issue altogether.* Someone should have been able to kindly explain to the receptionist that she can't leave the printer in direct sunlight, or she will soon no longer have a printer. **If she had become confrontational at that point, *only then* would it have been appropriate to bring it to you.**
- The other employee should have kept his mouth shut. This was an issue between the receptionist, the IT person, and you. *No matter what* the receptionist verbalized, it was NOT the other employee's place to become involved. It seems rather odd that he chose to do so.
- As a matter of fact, it is likely that this was part of a 'friendly'
  conversation, after which he saw an opportunity to stab the receptionist in the back. This is unacceptable. True professionals and respectable individuals *always* keep their noses out of issues that do not personally involve them.

These are just some things to think about. I'd love to tell you *the* surefire solution, but there probably isn't one. These issues are always multi-faceted, and never as clear-cut as they seem to be on the surface.

Ultimately, the decision is up to you. But just keep in mind that a wise leader never immediately assumes hearsay or complaints to be true, and good management always investigates thoroughly when any complaint or request for intervention is made.

A solid next step would be to sit them all (three) down individually, then address them in a group meeting to see if anyone's stories or attitudes change. Make note of these changes. If you've been dealing with people for any significant amount of time, it will become quickly apparent who is lying, who is telling the truth, and who you should even be having a conversation with in the first place.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 33):

As an employer, if your employee says she wants to leave, let her go.

If she asks other employees to leave with her, most definitely let her go.

Regarding comments: I wrote "if your employee says she wants to leave, let her go". I did *not* write "if someone tells you that your employee says she wants to leave, fire her".

Comment: Is it fair to fire someone just because she heard something about this employee? What's to say the person heard her complain and just misunderstood it?

Answer (score 21):

Let me present a different perspective. Most people do not behave as described just because they are jerks who should be fired. They do this because they are unhappy for some reason. Some people spread bad attitude as a sort of 'cry for help'. This could be caused by various things:

1. Personal problems
2. They became pessimistic due to recent changes in leadership or company structure
3. Highly stressful or demanding work
4. Feeling of insignificance
5. Being forced to do tasks inefficiently for stupid/no reasons

... Or they could really just be a terrible person who is difficult to work with.

Firing the receptionist now is just an easy way out. If she is otherwise a good employee who gets stuff done, you should at least try to work with her to figure out what's wrong. Perhaps you will uncover some problems in your organization you were not aware of, or which seem irrelevant to you but are a big deal for the receptionist.

My advice is this: Schedule a one-on-one meeting with her, make it feel safe for her to talk about anything and see where it gets you. This is a good idea regardless of the ultimate outcome. If there is a reason for her to be unhappy with her job, there is a good chance that the replacement receptionist would end up being unhappy as well.

The good outcome is that you will work with her to address her concerns, end up with a productive and happy employee and will have fixed some problems in your organization as a bonus. Or you discover that there is nothing you can do to help and get a new receptionist. At least you will know that you tried to fix the problem.

Comment: The OP said "...every time management addresses any issues with her...". This isn't a one-off event. Remember the old sayings "the first loss is the cheapest" and "don't throw good money after bad".

Comment: @alephzero: I mostly agree with you, but we do not know _how_ management usually addresses issues with the receptionist. It is extremely easy to descend into a downward spiral because of a completely stupid thing, such as, for example, failing to provide a sufficient explanation of a management's decision when it is enforced.

Comment: This classic explains it all:  http://www.bizjournals.com/bizjournals/how-to/human-resources/2012/01/how-to-get-rid-of-toxic-employees.html

Comment: @WesleyLong: The article does explain how to safely get rid of the employee, but I do not think it explains much else. The first step is to determine whether the employee really is toxic, or whether it's the company itself. Employees are humans and working with humans is hard, much to the dismay of the inhuman and soulless corporations.

Answer (score 9):

Let's combine some of the partially good answers into a more complete one:

What you have so far is hearsay. If the following are true, you need to get rid of her:

- She tried to get others to quit in order to harm the company, over the placement of a printer.
- She gets condescending every time management addresses any issues with her.

Talk to HR to figure out the legally correct way to get rid of her. The alternative is for management to address the issues with her, but obviously that doesn't work.

**However**, there are some assumptions you must confirm first.

1. The claim by the other employee is just a claim - see if you can verify it, so it becomes a fact. If you can't, you should look into whether you want to keep the other employee.
2. You said she wouldn't "take my reprimands". Is she upset because she's not allowed to move the printer, because she's been reprimanded, or because of the way you reprimanded her? There are many ways you can screw up when reprimanding someone, berating them in front of their colleagues, shouting at them, or not letting them tell their side of the story are some of the more obvious mistakes. Talk with your mentor to find out if she's right to be upset. If you don't have a mentor, find someone you can trust to be brutally honest with you.

Comment: + 1 for the advise to verify the hearsay before acting

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like she over-reacted. I don't think you should do the same thing. Work with your HR department and go through formal channels for repremanding an employee.

Who knows what was going on with her personal life at the time. Everyone makes mistakes. The real problem would be if she does not feel like you have the right to tell her what to do. If that is the case, she can reconsider her position. Let her know if this happens again, further action will be taken. It's your policy and legal requirements to determine what that is. She needs to be told explicitly what will happen if things don't change. She needs to be told not to discuss this with other employees.

Hopefully this is an isolated problem that will not occur again. You get to keep an otherwise useful employee who learns to appreciate what you've done for her. No one is perfect. The other employees didn't take her seriously. Tell the informer she has been given a second chance.

There is the risk that she has set a bad example and someone else may try and pull the same thing thinking they can get away with it. Well what will they get away with? Leaving?

Comment: "Well what will they get away with? Leaving?" -- even worse, talking about leaving as if it's a viable option ;-)

Comment: We don't even know if she did over-react. For all we know, the asker might have an overbearing manner, the receptionist might have made a casual meaningless frustrated comment after being reprimanded like "I wish she'd be less rude to everyone. Imagine if we all got fed up and walked out one day" then got back to work, and someone with a personal grudge or agenda saw it as an opportunity to score points with the boss at her expense. There's simply not enough to go on yet.